# visualizing what pointers indicate in printf

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I've come across such a function, very useful for my task of reversing a special type of words. 
I have a problem with that complicated pointer arithmetic in a while loop. How to display that array index number that stays behind eg. `word`,`dPtr` or `subword` (in current iteration) with printf ?

I only achieved the subtraction values (subword-word) and (dPtr-dest).

Is there a way to create a "foo" pointer that would be "zero" so that subtraction gives examined value alone?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* subword = NULL;
    char* dest;
    char* dPtr;

    size_t n, len;
    int len_int, n_int;

    char word[] = "-example-compound-word";
    len = strlen(word);
    len_int = (int)len;
    printf("string length is %d\n", len_int);
    dest = malloc(len+1);
    if (dest == NULL) return -1;

    dPtr = dest;

    while((subword = strrchr(word, '-'))!= NULL) {

        printf("the pointer values are: subword-word %ld, dPtr-dest %ld\n", (subword-word), (dPtr-dest));

        n = len - (subword-word) - (dPtr-dest);

        n_int = (int)n;
        printf("and the n is %d\n", n_int);

        if (n-1 > 0)
            strncpy(dPtr, subword+1, n-1);
        *subword = '\0';
        dPtr += n-1;
        *dPtr = '-';
        dPtr++;
    }
    strncpy(dPtr, word, len - (dPtr-dest));
    dest[len] = '\0';

    printf("the output is %s\n", dest);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your question how to print a pointer? `printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr);` does it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know that, but it only prints its address in hexadecimal format. I want to get integer value being the current processed array index. If it is only achievable using approach I presented in the code above, then how to make a "foo" pointer for such a subtraction to obtain absolute value of the processed index?

Comment: `subword - word` gives the index of the array element `subword` points to (as a `ptrdiff_t`). In general with `some_type arr[100]; some_type *ptr = &arr[12];`, `ptr - arr` gives the index of the element `ptr` points to (here 12). And what do you mean by the "absolute value of the processed index"? You get the index by subtracting the base pointer, in your case `word` resp. `dest`, like you did. I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: are you trying to print just the subwords in the compound word? As in 'example', 'compound', 'word'?

Comment: @DanZimm - no, I want to transform it in that way, another-test- to -test-another. But that's not the topic of my question ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer - I think that You answered my question. I didn't know that `word` and `dest` act as a "zero", I thought they are not the first array elements... Big thanks! It would be nice if You post that as an answer - I'd accept it.

Comment: @Peter just to make explicit about why Daniel's answer is right, pointer arithmetic is different than integer arithmetic because the addent is implicitly multipled by the sizeof the type you are operating on.  That is why this works.  Try to do pointer arithmetic on a void * and you will see it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pointer `p` into an array (or into a `malloc`ed memory block acting as an array), you obtain the index of the pointed-to array element by subtracting a pointer to the first element from `p`.

In the case of `subword`, you can simply use `word`, since array names are in most contexts (not as arguments of `sizeof`) converted into pointers to their first element, so in the expression

```
subword - word
```

the array `word` is converted to a pointer to its first element, and an equivalent form explicitly using a `char*` is

```
subword - &word[0]
```

In the case of `dPtr`, the base pointer to be subtracted is `dest`, which points to the first byte of the `malloc`ed memory block, and

```
dPtr - dest
```

gives the corresponding index. In the case of `char*`, the index is the same as the offset in bytes, but in general, the subtraction of two pointers to the same object type pointing into the same array (or one past the end) also yields the number of elements between the two pointers, not the byte offset.

Note that the result of subtracting two pointers is a value of type `ptrdiff_t`, and the length modifier to be used in `printf` for such values is `t`, so

```
printf("the pointer values are: subword-word %ld, dPtr-dest %ld\n", (subword-word), (dPtr-dest));
```

should properly be

```
printf("the pointer values are: subword-word %td, dPtr-dest %td\n", (subword-word), (dPtr-dest));
```

or the values should be cast to `long int` if the `l` length modifier is used.